# How i can hidden the selected items in my popup widget entity reference view widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

at first she work perfect, but i have added a javascript function : when i uncheck items she will be removed, the problem is  :
 when i add items, always  all items was showing in my popup widget, how i can removed the existants items or other solution indicating the items are already Selected??
printed below the screens and js code :

[image]

[image]

[image]

```js
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.entityreferenceViewWidget = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

      
      
      var checkboxes = '#modal-content input.entity-reference-view-widget-select';
      var selectAllSelector = '#entityreference-view-widget-select-all';
      $(selectAllSelector).unbind('click').data('unselect', 0).click(function() {
        if ($(this).data('unselect')) {
          $(checkboxes).removeAttr('checked');
          $(this).data('unselect', 0).text(Drupal.t('Select all'));
        }
        else {
          $(checkboxes).attr('checked', 'checked');
          $(this).data('unselect', 1).text(Drupal.t('Unselect all'));
        }
        return false;
      });

      if (settings.entityReferenceViewWidget) {
        var ervwSetttings = settings.entityReferenceViewWidget.settings;
        if (ervwSetttings.cardinality != -1 || $(checkboxes).length === 0) {
          $(selectAllSelector).remove();
        }

        var selector = '#' + ervwSetttings.table_id + ' input[type=checkbox]:checked';
        var selected_ids = '';
        $(selector).each(function() {
          selected_ids += $(this).val() + ';';
        });
        if (selected_ids.length > 0) {
          $('input[name="selected_entity_ids"]').val(selected_ids.substring(0, selected_ids.length - 1)).trigger('change');
        }

        // We need to pass the settings via an hidden field because Views doesn't
        // allow us to pass data between ajax requests.
        if (settings.entityReferenceViewWidget.serialized) {
          $('input[name="ervw_settings"]').val(settings.entityReferenceViewWidget.serialized);
        }
      }



    $('.field-widget-entityreference-view-widget  input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
     $(this).onclick = function() {
          console.log(1)
           }
    $(this).addClass('uncheck-to-remove').attr('title',Drupal.t('Uncheck to remove this item')).click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').hide(500);
 

     });
           });

 
    }
 // }
};
  // Create a new ajax command, ervw_draggable that is called to make the rows
  // of the widget draggable.
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.ervw_draggable = function(ajax, response, status) {
    $('#' + response.selector + ' tr').each(function(){
      var el = $(this);
      Drupal.tableDrag[response.selector].makeDraggable(el.get(0));
      el.find('td:last').addClass('tabledrag-hide');
      if ($.cookie('Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight') == 1) {
        el.find('.tabledrag-handle').hide();
      }
      else {
        el.find('td:last').hide();
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write any code for this (well the hidding part got to be written with js code atm), it is just configuration.

To not display items allready selected in the modal alimented with the view you created you must have a contextual filter on the nid of your nodes. Edit this contextual filter and check the "Exclude" under "More" menu (next to the add multiple values).

check this video : http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/entity-reference-view-widget at the 8:00 mark. The video explains pretty much any basic configuration for this widget.